# Django forms, should i write front-end code to display the custom form?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, django, reactjs

```
class Teacher(models.Model):
    name = CharField


class Child(models.Model):
    name = CharField
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(
        'Teacher',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='nodes',
    )
```

I am wring a config page, doesn't like normal solution, use django template render the html page, and update with same template, I can click "add" then I can input the new children information, in other words, I can add multiple children with one teacher.

```
class TeacherCreate(View):
    template_name = 'config/teacher_add.html'

    def get(self, request):
        teacher_form = TeacherForm()
        children_list = [ChildrenForm(), ]

        return render(request, self.template_name, {
                'teacher_form': teacher_form, 
                'children_list': children_list, 
            })

    def post(self, request):
        received_json = json.loads(request.body)
        children_list = received_json['children_list']
        children_form_list = []
        teacher_form = TeacherForm({'name': received_json['name']})
        valid = True

        try:
            with transaction.atomic():
                teacher = None
                if teacher_form.is_valid():
                    teacher = teacher_form.save()
                else:
                    valid = False

                for child in children_list:
                    children_form = ChildrenForm(child)
                    if children_form.is_valid():
                        if valid:
                            children = children_form.save(commit=False)
                            children.teacher = teacher
                            children.save()
                    else:
                        valid = False
                    children_form_list.append(children_form)

                if not valid:
                    # rollback
                    raise KeyError
        except KeyError:
            # rollback
            pass

        if valid:
            return redirect(reverse("config:teacher_list"))
        else:
            return HttpJson({
                    'teacher_form': teacher_form,   # here I have to convert to normal data, and extract errors
                    'children_list': children_form_list, # here I have to convert to normal data, and extract errors
                })
```

but as you can see, I have to convert form to normal dictionary data to client, and client must be use some template engine render the json data to html page. that is to say, I have to write same render code(not same template syntax), one use javascript's template and one use django's template. So should I just use reactjs render the form part, that mean( the server just render whole html page but not include the form part, the form part use reactjs or whatever other javascript code request again, and render)

Answer (score 0):

For this I typically just create a small template (call it a component) and return the `render` on the template. If you want to also pass back some extra variables you can use `render_to_string` and insert it into a dictionary like:

```
return JsonResponse({
  "html": render_to_string(template, context, request),
  "var1": "value",
  "var2": "value"
})
```

Then access it in javascript with `response.html`.

This does add a little bit of extra work to your server and is not ideal for websites that receive a lot of traffic. You shouldn't need react if you just want to render a response easily in javascript.

EDIT: Alternatively there are some templating engines you can use (moustache, handlebars). You can create your template in django, render it in the page as a javascript variable and then render based off that template.